# Possible to pass literal character * as a command line argument in Bash?

Tags: bash, parameters

Take the bash script wtf.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
echo $2
echo $3
```

```
./wtf.sh 1 2 3 
1 
2
3

./wtf.sh * * * 



end

./wtf.sh 1 * * 
1
wtf.sh
wtf.sh 

./wtf.sh 1 "*" "*"
1
wtf.sh
wtf.sh
```

I'm aware that `*` is special parameter in Bash but does that mean it's impossible to pass the `*` by itself as a literal character from the command line? What I was expecting was

```
./wtf.sh * * * 
* 
* 
*
```

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass a literal <kbd>*</kbd> by:

- Putting it in quotes: `"*"`
- Putting it in apostrophes: `'*'`
- Backslash escaping it: `\*`

Those are all equivalent (in this case).

The reason that didn't work is that your script has a problem: when you don't quote `$1` (and `$2` and `$3`), you are telling the shell to perform pathname expansion and word splitting on their contents. That's actually almost never what you want -- and it clearly isn't what you want in this case. So your script should read:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$1"
echo "$2"
echo "$3"
```

Here, the arguments must be surround with double quotes (`"$1"`), which allows parameter expansion to take place, but inhibits pathname expansion and word splitting.

Comment: I just tested with that modification of " " and the results are still the same. That said I was able to get the expected output if  in addition to your script modification I also added quotes around each asterisk  from the command line ./wtf.sh "*"  , output was * . Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Peter: Yes, you need quotes in both places. You need to quote the `*` so that it isn't expanded on the command-line, *and* you need to quote `$1` so that the expansion isn't glob-expanded. I tried to make the answer clearer.

Comment: Backslash worked for me perfectly! Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing `*` as a value of an command line option and extracting the command line option using `getopt` then you can use `-S*`, where -S is command line option and `*` is its value. Please note that there is no space between `S` and `*`. If you give space then path expansion happens automatically.

Comment: It seems you didn't understand the question and the problem: rici's answer spotted the main problem (which is, unfortunately, the most common problem with people trying to program in shell): lacks of quotes!